# Using VSCode's vscode-text-field from the VSCode Toolkit UI with Vue 3 in an Extension

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode Toolikit UI with Vue.
I am following the documentation on how to use vscode-text-field and failing to get at the entered data:
It works if I use plan old <input statement  in conjunction with v-model
but not when i use **vscode-text-input**

I suspect something really obvious is missing but I can't see what that might be.

```
    export default defineComponent({
        components:{},
        data() {
            return {
                dj: "",
                user: "",
                pass: ""
            };
        },
    methods: {
        validate() {
            console.log("user " , this.user);    <=== doesn't display anything
            console.log("password " , this.pass);   <=== doesn't display anything
            console.log("dj " , this.dj);   <==== this works and displays the entered data    
            vscode.postMessage({
                command: "hello",
                text: "Input validated",
            })}
        }
    })  
    </script>

<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Enter credentials</h1>  
        <input type="text" v-model="dj"/>  
        <vscode-text-field type="text" v-model="user" maxlength="8">Userid</vscode-text-field><br><br>
        <vscode-text-field type="password"  v-model="pass">Password</vscode-text-field><br><br>
        <vscode-button v-on:click="validate">Accept</vscode-button>
    </div>
</template>
```

Further investigation and I find that this "works" but is a bit kludgy:    but this is a 'one way' setting of the value rather than using v-model which is a 'two way'bind.
**This is basically the long hand form of v-model**
So again, I suspect that I am missing something rather obvious in my attempts above.

```
<script>

methods: {
    handleInput(event: any) {
        this.user = event.target.value;
    }
  }
</script>
<template>
<vscode-text-field maxlength="8" @input="handleInput">Userid</vscode-text-field>
</template>
```